# NSTextView Scrolling

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

How to make a `NSTextView` scrollable ?

## Problem:

- Text View is displayed but is not scrollable. I have to resize the window to see more contents

## Question:

- How to make the text view scrollable.

## Code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    private let textView                = NSTextView()

    //MARK: Manage Views

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTextView()
    }


    private func setupTextView() {

        textView.isEditable      = false

        view.addSubview(textView)

        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put the text view in a scroll view to make the text view scrollable. I have not done this in code so I cannot provide an example. It is easier to add a text view to your view controller in Interface Builder because the text view object includes a scroll view for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`NSTextView` doesn't scroll, place the text view inside a `NSScrollView`. Class method `scrollableTextView()` of `NSTextView` returns a `NSTextView` in a `NSScrollView`.

```
private var textView:NSTextView?

private func setupTextView() {

    let scrollView = NSTextView.scrollableTextView()
    textView = scrollView.documentView as? NSTextView

    textView?.isEditable      = false

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! much cleaner solution that my answer. Now it makes sense why using Storyboard you can directly add an object called *Scrollable Text View*